# Embed Ajax requests in bind events (XHR)

Tags: php, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest, bind

I'm trying to find the answer somewhere around but i can't,

So i'm having a .bind() event and I want when's triggered to make a get query from a php file with JSON like AJAX does.

I have tried the following which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#adivhere").bind("valuesChanged", function(){ 

                            // Some variables here 
var max2 = 10
var min2 = 5

                            //The classic AJAX Request
function afunc(max2,min2){
var xmlhttp;  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
}else  {    // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}


                           //The classic AJAX onreadystatechange function
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{ if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){    

                         //The code triggered
var fets = jQuery.parseJSON( xmlhttp.responseText );
var t = fets.date.split(/[-]/); 
var d = new Date(t[0], t[1], t[2]);
alert(d);   

}}  

                        //The XHR request with the .php file and the
                        // two values that sends
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdates.php?max2="+max2+"&min2="+min2,true);
xmlhttp.send();
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery, so this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('#adivhere').bind('valuesChanged',function(){ 
        var max2 = 10;
        var min2 = 5;

        $.getJSON('getdates.php?callback=?', {max2: max2, min2: min2}, function(json){
            alert(json);

            var t = json.date.split(/[-]/);

            if (t && t.length) {
                var d = new Date(t[0], t[1], t[2]);
                alert(d);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There's already an awesome $.getJSON method in jQuery that will do all of the heavy lifting for you, including return your results as JSON.

You'll need to make your `getdates.php` script echo the `callback` and wrap your results in parentheses so it returns as actual jQuery.

Comment: Thanks.
That should work I asume but `alert(json);` doesn't happen. 
At the moment `getdates.php` echoes a Json string is that the problem?

And that code above gives: `getdates.php?callback=?max2=10&min2=5` . Am i correct?

Comment: @DDL449 The action that you're binding, `valuesChanged`, needs to be triggered. I don't think that `valuesChanged` is a default action, so you'll need to either change it to `change` or actually trigger it by using `$('#adivhere').trigger('valuesChanged');` when the action you want happens.

Comment: @DDL449 Actually it should convert to `get dates.php?callback=?&max2=10&min2=5`, where the second `?` will be replaced with something like json_callback1283754914 automatically by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There are several "errors" in your script:

- "afunc" is never called, so why should it be executed?
- the parenthesis are not closed properly; at the end there are two missing: )}

Comment: Thanks. Yes it misses a }).
So if I omit `function afunc(max2,min2){` and the corresponding closing parenthesis would work?